# How to tar multiple files with the find command

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I am trying to tar multiple files using the find command. I want to find all the files in the directory that contain a specific string in the file name and then tar those files. The string that I am want to find in the file name is the date.

For instance, I have a file name named ulog.20120914.log

What I'm doing right now is:

```
DAYTWOPREV=`date +%Y%m%d --date='2 days ago'`

function archive {
    cd $1;
    if [ ! -d archive ]; then
        mkdir archive;
    fi

TMPFILE=`mktemp`;
    find . -maxdepth 1 -name "${DAYTWOPREV}*" -type f -print0  > $TMPFILE;


    TARFILE=archive/${DAYTWOPREV}$2.tar;
    if [ ! -e $TARFILE ]; then
        echo tar cfT $TARFILE /dev/null;
        tar cfT $TARFILE /dev/null;
    fi  

cat $TMPFILE | xargs -0r tar rf $TARFILE
    cat $TMPFILE | xargs -0r rm -rf
    rm -f $TMPFILE;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU tar (i.e. on Linux, not AIX, or HP-UX or ...):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep -z "${DAYTWOPREV}" | tar -cvf archive.tar --null -T /dev/stdin
```

Comment: when i try this it gives me two of the same file in the archive.tar

Comment: If the three tar files match the name you specified, then that's the correct behaviour.  If you wanted all the names that match except those that end with `.tar`, you have to tell `find` (or `tar`) to exclude the names you want excluded.  You might also need the `-type f` option (but tar files match that criterion anyway).

Comment: The `"*${DAYTWOPREV}*"` bit is problematic, because, in double quotes, the shell might expand that before handing it to `find`. However, putting it in single quotes means the variable won't get expanded either. Editing to suggest an alternative...

Comment: ok i changed my edit...i was trying to respond inijus comment but responded to yours instead...but im just testing it with one file at the moment but there are two in the archive...

Comment: What you wrote originally was fine; the double quotes mean the shell won't expand the metacharacters (`*`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Doh... you're right. Time for that second cup of coffee... So, `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*${DAYTWOPREV}*" -print0 | tar ...` should also work, with out the (slight) overhead of adding `grep` into the equation.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell GNU `tar` to read the list of files to archive from its standard input:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "${DAYTWOPREV}*" -type f | tar -czf archive.tar.gz -T -
```

The `-T -` is the magic; `-T` means 'read file list from given file', and the (second) `-` indicates 'the file is standard input'.  (I added the `z` option to compress the file using `gzip` and named the tar file accordingly.  You might prefer `j` and `bzip2` with the `.bz2` extension.  You might find your `tar` supports `xz` compression natively; the option letter is `-J` on Mac OS X and BSD. And BSD supports `--lzma` for LZMA compression.)

Also, with GNU `tar`, you can specify option `--null` (and then with GNU `find` use `-print0`) to handle even file names containing newlines.  As written, this runs into issues if the file names contain newlines; otherwise, it works one file per line reliably enough, spaces and all.

Comment: Getting...
tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: `-F` is something completely different with GNU tar. Obviously, it would help if you could specify what version you have...

Comment: I misremembered the option letter; it is `-T` and not `-F` as I originally wrote.  I've fixed that aspect of the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler im using version 1.15.1 and it doesnt give more information about the specific issue

Comment: Time to upgrade to a newer version of GNU `tar`; the current version is at least 1.23.  Version 1.15.1 was released at the end of December 2004.  Quite a number of new and useful features have been added since then, notably support for multiple compression mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, tar does have an option (**`r` instead of `c`**) that fixes the "multiple invocations of tar" problem with some of these other solutions.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*20120914*' -exec tar rvf archive.tar {} +

find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*20120914*' -print0 | xargs -0 tar rvf archive.tar
```

Actually, it looks like you're already using that. What exactly is missing from your existing solution? (Other than - I don't *think* you actually need the tar file to exist, so the /dev/null creation is an unnecessary step. However, I'm not in a position to test right now)

Comment: You should emphasize that you're using the `-r` option to `tar`; it is crucial to the safe operation of your commands.  (I was about to castigate you for unsafety, but then noted the `-r` instead of `-c`.)

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

```
tar -cf $TARFILE ${DAYTWOPREV}*
```